# How to adjust the indent of the header of a TableView in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I know how to set the header text and style it, but for the life of me, I cannot find anything that explains how to adjust the indent of the text. This is what I tried:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int){
    let header = view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView
    header.textLabel?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    header.textLabel?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: header.leftAnchor, constant: 15).isActive = true
}
```

The code above (and every variation I've tried) results in the error:

> Unable to activate constraints because they have no common ancestor.

Which causes me to say to my computer, *"If `header.textLabel` got me to the `UILabel`, and `header` is indeed a `UITableViewHeaderFooterView`, I reckon that you oughta know that one is the ancestor of another!"*

Answer (score 5):

You can do this by first setting the `separatorInset` for the entire `TableView` like this:

```
let headerInset: CGFloat = 50
tableView.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.init(top: 0, left: headerInset, bottom: 0, right: 0)
```

Then if you want to position the cells of the table to lineup with the edge of the `TableView`, you can do this in the `forRowAt indexPath` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    cell.separatorInset = UIEdgeInsets.zero

}
```

Comment: This works at first, but when you push to another view controller, and come back to the screen with tableview, the inset is lost- and even if the separator inset is set in the viewdidappear, the inset is gone.